# Personalized input, can't redirect to other urls

Tags: html, css, input, styles

So, I'm trying to edit some personalized inputs, but somehow I can't get the input type submit to work properly, I've tried onclick=blabla redirect and tried associating it with a function to redirect, so far nothing, stays on the same page.

i.imgur.com/265RGMu.jpg

This is the form

```
    <form method="post" id="fields">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" >
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    <input type="submit" value="Lost Password">
```

this is it's css:

```
 #fields {
    width: 220px;
    height: 155px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -110px;
    margin-top: -75px;

    -webkit-animation: login 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: login 1s ease-in-out;
    animation: login 1s ease-in-out;
}

#fields input[type="text"],
#fields input[type="password"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .49);

    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 6px;

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F2F2F2 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px #d9d9d9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px #d9d9d9;

    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#fields input[type="text"]:focus,
#fields input[type="password"]:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px #a7a7a7;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 0px #a7a7a7;
}

#fields input:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#fields input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #5b6ddc;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .49);

    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #5466da;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5466da 0%, #768ee4 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #5466da 0%, #768ee4 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5466da 0%, #768ee4 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5466da 0%, #768ee4 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #5466da 0%, #768ee4 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #9ab1ec;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #9ab1ec;

    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#fields input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #5f73e9;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5f73e9 0%, #859bef 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #5f73e9 0%, #859bef 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5f73e9 0%, #859bef 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5f73e9 0%, #859bef 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #5f73e9 0%, #859bef 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #aab9f4;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #aab9f4;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Wasted complete hours trying to fix this,

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a javascript question (rather than css/style)

Comment: please share some more inputs on problem.

Comment: I see that your `form` doesn't have an `action`. But that would be too easy, wouldn't it. Yes, you just left the action out in this example here, and the real form, on your site, does have one. Never mind me then. ::slinks away::

Comment: Seriously now, how are you trying to redirect? Can you show the code? Moreover, _why_ are you trying to redirect? Can't you simply go to the page you want to go to?

Comment: The thing with action is that if I place it to go where I want it to go, all the 3 input submit's will do the same.                     http://i.imgur.com/265RGMu.jpg   this is an actually screenshot of the inputs

Comment: So, again, can you show the code with which you tried to access the other pages in the buttons? You know, the most important part of the question, the bit that you actually need help with, and all you said was "I can't get the input type submit to work properly, I've tried onclick=blabla". To which the only thing to say is, yeah, onclick=blabla doesn't work, you know.

Comment: I do want to help, I just need to know what you've done wrong before I can tell you how to right it.

Comment: I'll be home in a couple of hours and will upload the full content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your Problem. I think that your idea of the structure of website is not the best.
You could user links instead of buttons to "redirect" to a register page or whatever. You can style them like your button.

If you want to send the input of your forms to the destination page, you can do it with a redirect in JS. But you can only provide the username. The password would be send in plain text in the URL.
Example (user the Button-Type instead of submit):

```
<form id="fields" action="login.html">
  <input id="user" type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br /> 
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="redirect_loginfrom('register')"/><br />
 <input type="button" value="Lostpassword" onclick="redirect_loginfrom('lostpassword')" /><br />
</form>
```

See full soruce here: http://jsfiddle.net/BmYck/2/

Comment: Wasn't completly what I searched for but I've done some alterations to the JS and it works properly, thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion: you could add a placeholder text for your input fields. i've updated the fiddle